# how do i create a flutter project without the android and iOS build folders, only for web build only?

Tags: flutter, cross-platform, flutter-web

I would like to create a flutter project but I don't want to include the android and iOS version build folders and functionalities.

How can I make this to create with the web build only?

Answer (score 10):

`flutter create --platforms=web <name>`

See `flutter --help create` for full documentation of the `platforms` flag, as well as all the other creation options.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. It hasn't been mentioned on the CLI reference.

Answer (score 5):

If you only need **Web, Linux and Windows** :

`flutter create --platforms=web,linux,windows`

---

If you only need **Web** :

`flutter create --platforms=web`

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to create a project for web only. The `flutter create` command only takes one argument and that is the project directory/name. `flutter create <DIRECTORY>`, like shown on the [Flutter CLI reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/reference/flutter-cli).

If you don't need an iOS/Android app you can delete the `ios` and `android`folders.

And to build your app for web you can run `flutter build web`.

Comment: You should run `flutter --help create`; it has many flags.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create your project only for Android & iOS, use this command:

```
--platforms=android,ios
```

Example:

```
flutter create [PROJECT_NAME] --platforms=android,ios
```